# Validating names that could contain <> symbols ie potentially malicious javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

One of my GUIs was giving a message “A potentially dangerous Request. Form value was detected from the client”
This is because names can contain <> characters.
To stop this message one can add ValidateRequest="false” to web.config.
This leaves the application vulnerable to malicious input eg

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/xss-attack-examples/

If the GUI converts <> to escape characters the stored procedure will need to convert them back, so I could still get malicious javascript when the browser displays the name.

The only consolation I can think of is that the name is limited to 90 characters.  How long would a string of javascript need to be to act maliciously?

This link gives some tags to look out for, but is not exhaustive.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx
Any suggestions?  I'm using visual studio 2008 with asp.net 3.5 - C#

Comment: hey do you want any javascript code to disallow use of special characters as input or do you want any javascript code to restrict the name to alphabets or alpha numeric

Comment: At the moment I am not using any Javascript code.  I would use the C# program to disallow special characters.  However <> needs to be allowed.  At the moment I have no plans to use Javascript at all, but am open to the possibility.  Among other issues I don't know Javascript.

Comment: Experts exchange advised me to store them as escape characters in the database.  The browser will render them as <>.  Does that make sense to you?
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_28281978.html